# Как эмулировать нажатие клавиши в Linux в режиме ядра?

Tags: linux, c, ядро

Пишу драйвер мыши, позволяющий имитировать нажатия клавиш клавиатуры с помощью точек и тире. Но те способы, которые удалось найти на форумах(и понять), используют средства пространства пользователя, т.е. мне не подходят. Можете подсказать, как это сделать или указать, где это можно прочитать?

Если что, использую Ubuntu 20.04.3

Comment: Смотрел как работает `hid-replay`? Он использует кое-что из ядра, что можешь сделать и ты.